# Php mysql query syntax error (Unknown field)

Tags: php

```
include("db_connector.php");
    $soru = "asdasds";
    $tip = 1;
    $soruId = 0;

        $sql = "insert into sor (anketId,soruMetni,tip) values (".$_SESSION['anket'].",".$soru.",".$tip.")";
        $islem = mysql_query($sql)or die(mysql_error());;
        if(isset($islem))
        {
            $soruId = mysql_insert_id();
        }else
        {
            header("refresh:2;sorular.php");
        }
```

this code give an error like this : ﻿Unknown column 'asdasds' in 'field list'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just add `'` before and after every variable in query. You cannot pass string to query without adding single quote `'`.

Change From:

```
$sql = "insert into sor (anketId,soruMetni,tip) values (".$_SESSION['anket'].",".$soru.",".$tip.")";
```

to :

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `sor` (anketId,soruMetni,tip) 
        VALUES ('".$_SESSION['anket']."', '".$soru."', '".$tip."')";
```

Comment: thank you man problem solved :)

Comment: @BatuhanGÜNGÖR please accept my answer if you found it useful.

Comment: I will... 8 min later :) this is a proc

Comment: @BatuhanGÜNGÖR sure :)

Answer (score 3):

You need to change the SQL statement in this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `sor` (anketId,soruMetni,tip) 
        VALUES ('".$_SESSION['anket']."','".$soru."',".$tip.")";
```

Strings needs to be encapsulated with a single quote. :)